# Deletion of chained mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to keep only the recent email, and delete old emails in a conversation.  the recent mail will have the entire conversation of that particular message.
Is it possible in outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to
[Use Conversation Clean Up to delete redundant messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-conversation-clean-up-to-delete-redundant-messages-70179d54-fa57-48ce-95fd-416d72e5ccd4),
to delete emails in the conversation (or email thread) that are completely
contained in more recent replies.

This is done on the *Home* tab, in the *Delete* group, by clicking *Clean Up*
and then *Clean Up Conversation*.

The above Microsoft article describes more options that are available for
this command.

[image]